# SMOTE not working in Random forest for Hold Out Sample

Tags: random, random-forest

I am using SMOTE for oversampling, The event rate in my Traning sample is  ~4%. The results validates well in the Training sample but does not validate well in Hold Out Sample. I have tried different combination for Perc.Over and Perc.Under .

1. How do I select the number for Perc.Over and Perc. Under
2. How do I ensure it validates well in teh Hold out sample as well

Answer (score 0):

You should set perc.under to capture all majority class samples and perc.over to boost your minority class samples to at least 10% to remove the class imbalance problem.
If the problem still exists then it could suggest there is a lot of 'noisy' samples in your minority class. Try it and see if it works!